# Ceiling fan wiring

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

[image: ceiling fan switch][image: wiring diagram]I replaced a ceiling fan. The light and fan are controlled by a switch on the wall. I'm having difficulties connecting the wires coming from the switch to the wires in the ceiling fan and the main power supply. There's 5 wires coming from the switch to the ceiling fan with little labels on them.

1. Black "live in"
2. Black "fan out"
3. White "common out"
4. White "neutural in"
5. Red "light out"

I think i know what to do with wires #2, 3, and 5, but I'm unsure of what to do with the two "in" wires.

Comment: What make and model is the fan switch? Can you post photos of it? Do you know what make and model the old fan was, for that matter?

Comment: I added a photo of the switch, it's a Hunter. I'm not sure what the old fan was, I got rid of it a long time ago. It was maybe approximately 20 years old.

Comment: can you turn the breaker off and get us photos of the inside of the switch box + any make/model labeling on the switch itself please?

Answer (score 1):

Black "Live in" is attached to the black power " switched hot" comming from the switch

black "fan out" is attached to the black lead from the fan.

White "common out"  is attached to the white lead from the fan.

White "neutral in"  Is attached to the white neutral in the box.

Red  "Light out"  Is attached to the blue or red lead from the fan.

This is normal for a fan controlled by a hand remote or wall switch remote.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding the black "live in" wire, should it be attached to the black wire from the box?

Comment: I added a diagram of how I currently have the ceiling fan wired. When I turn the power on, the fan doesn't work and the light blinks one every five seconds.

Comment: black "live in' should be attached to the  black from the power supply.

Comment: Are there pull chains for fan and light switching on the fan?  If so the fan may be off from the pull chain switch.  Some lights and fan motors have to be programed to the switch after power is lost or interrupted.

Comment: Yes, there are pull chains. You were right, I pulled the chain for the fan, and now it works. However, the light still won't fully turn on. It just blinks once every five seconds or so.

Comment: look in the fan instructions for light programing.  If there is none, try to refer to the instructions for the fan control switch.  Unfortunately I have had such issues with fan remotes and the lights and the problem was the remote receiver. The reciever may not be compatible with an LED light.

Comment: @RMDman do not give up now

Comment: I put in different bulbs, which solved the problem. Thank you so much for your help!